# Bootstrap tabs and jQuery event firing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

As i am newbie `JavaScript` and `jQuery` so i am facing problem with 
the simple things.

I have created 3 bootstrap tabs.`(i.e. mainstream,substream,delayedstream)`,
In all tabs i have created a `vlc players` using `jQuery`, the players works 
perfectly i didn't face any issue with that.

when the tab change event is triggered (i.e. when the switching to the other `tab`) I am calling the `jQuery function`. That is responsible for the creation of my `vlc player`.

Here is the code i wrote to detect `tab change event` and `trigger` the corresponding function:-

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){ 
    var target = $(e.target).attr('href');
    if(target=="#att_mainstream")
    {
        mainvideoObject.mainshow();
    }   
    if(target=="#att_substream")
    {
        subvideoObject.subshow();
    }
    if(target=="#att_delayedstream")
    {
        delayedvideoObject.delayedshow();
    }
});
```

Whenever we switch the `tabs` that particular `tab function` will be called.

Here is the real issue, whenever i switch the `tabs`, the creation of the `vlcplayer` is increasing to that particular tab.

(In brief to the problem when i first execute, In `first tab` By default it is only one `player` is created, When i visit the `second` or `third` `tab` and come back to the `first tab` again and resulting the creation of one more `player` in the `first tab` and it keep increasing on every consecutive visit to that particular `tab` and this same goes to the `second` and `third tab`, It keeps increasing the one extra `player` on every visit)

My thinking towards this problem is, may be it is calling the `function for every tab change event` and resulting the extra creation of the `player`.

So here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apv59tw1/1/) for the complete code.

P.S. the `code` and output looks very clumsy as it is tightly formed. But we can observe the problem in `Inspect Element` option of browser that how on every `tab change` it is creating one extra player to that particular `tab`.

**Here are the some snaps that will give the better understanding of the problem.**

1)It is when i first execute it.(only one player is created)

[image]

2)After visiting the other tabs i.e. `second` or `third` `tab` and come back to the first tab again.

[image]

I am not getting the what the real issue is?

Any help that will be gratefully for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

My previous suggestion is down the bottom. But a better approach is probably to check if it already exists before calling xxxvideoObject.xxxshow():

```
    $("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){ 
        var target = $(e.target).attr('href');
        var LastTab = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');

        if(target=="#att_mainstream") {            
            if($('#mainvideoOverlay').length == 0)
            {                   
                mainvideoObject.mainshow();
            };
        }   
        if(target=="#att_substream") {            
            if($('#subvideoOverlay').length == 0)
            {            
                subvideoObject.subshow();
            };
        }
        if(target=="#att_delayedstream") {              
            if($('#delayedvideoOverlay').length == 0)
            {                   
                delayedvideoObject.delayedshow();
            };
        }
    });
```

---

You could use the on hide event. Add the following code directly underneath your on show event handler:

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('hide.bs.tab', function(e){            
        var target = $(e.target).attr('href');

        if(target=="#att_mainstream")
        {
            $('#mainvideoOverlay').remove();
        }   
        if(target=="#att_substream")
        {
            $('#subvideoOverlay').remove();
        }   
        if(target=="#att_delayedstream")
        {
            $('#delayedvideoOverlay').remove();
        }   
});
```

Comment: if this solution works for you please don't forget to mark it as answered :)